# MYSQL selecting from 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to select from 3 tables: products, bids, orders.

In the bids, it's just a bid id, username, amount, timestamp, date, item

In the products, it has multiple, price, descriptions, images, location, shipping etc

in orders it's addresses, username, names, product, shipped

I am trying to select all rows from all of those tables where the username=? so I can check if the item has been shipped via the $query->shipped(ordertable) or paid $query->status(ordertable) instead of doing a foreach and another query

Now, I had a query which was working for 2 of those tables, but when I addeed orders, no products where showing:

**Working**

```
SELECT * FROM bids,products WHERE bids.username=? AND NOW() > products.enddate GROUP BY item ORDER BY amount DESC
```

**Not working, but need this type of query**

```
SELECT * FROM bids,products,orders WHERE bids.username=? AND NOW() > products.enddate GROUP BY item ORDER BY amount DESC
```

How would I go about selecting orders too. I have attached the structure of the tables for reference.:

**Products -- Need all**

[image: products]

**Orders -- Need all**

[image: orders]

**Bids -- Need all**

[image: bids]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to accurately select from multiple tables, you must have foreign keys. Please note that your first query is broken without a join by a foreign key column.

I see that your `Bids` table has a column `item`. If this column is what I think it is, the name of the column should be something like `product_id`, and it should be specified as a foreign key reference to the `id` column of your `Products` table. This is how we can make sure every bid is for a valid product.

Given that the `item` column in `Bids` is a foreign key to `Products`, your first query would be correctly stated (in terms of referential integrity and cardinality) as:

```
SELECT * FROM bids INNER JOIN products ON bids.item = products.id
WHERE bids.username=? AND NOW() > products.enddate
ORDER BY amount DESC
```

If you want to make sure you retrieve all product records regardless of whether they have bids, then use a `RIGHT JOIN` above instead of `INNER JOIN`, and change your username filter to `(bids.username = ? OR bids.username IS NULL)`.

Now for your second query, the one you're asking for help on. Given the schema you've provided, there's no good way to represent such a query. I'm afraid the query could never function correctly due to diverging widening cardinality across `Bids` and `Orders`.

If you still want to try, here is a starting point for the three-table join:

```
SELECT * FROM products
LEFT JOIN bids ON products.id = bids.item
LEFT JOIN orders ON products.id = orders.product
```

The left joins will ensure you retrieve all product records. The problem with this, in terms of cardinality, is you're going to get too many rows for each product (the number of bids for each product multiplied by the number of orders for that product).

Comment: Hypothetically, if I wanted to join all three, what would I need to make my common key, at the moment, products.id, bids.product and orders.product are all the same.

Comment: Ok, see my updated answer. I've fixed some things, and tried to be more clear on why the join will be a problem. Also specified inner joins, in case you want to make sure you get back every product record.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have enough rep to comment on gknicker's answer, I am forced to provide a separate answer. I was going to suggest using LEFT JOIN as a solution, but given the problems already outlined, you could also, as a last resort, add a new field to the database table that allows for easier joining of the tables you are having trouble with and set the foreign keys accordingly.